# Django Admin: Email Id Autofill and Related_name= Issue

Tags: python, django, database

This is the code that I have in my models.py. I'm trying to develop a small website using only the Django Admin.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
   STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Project Manager', 'Project Manager'),
       ('Technician', 'Technician'),
       ('Tester', 'Tester')
   )
   STATUS_CHOICE_1 = (
       ('Work Assigned', 'Work Assigned'),
       ('Work in Progress', 'Work in Progress'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
       ('Completed', 'Completed')
   )
   Project_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Project_Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Admin_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Admin_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Project_Manager_1_users')
   Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Project_Manager_2_users')
   Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Technician_1_users')
   Technician_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Technician_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Technician_2_users')
   Technician_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Technician_3_users')
   Technician_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Tester_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Tester_1_users')
   Tester_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='Example@gmail.com')
   Additional_User_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Ad_1_users')
   Additional_User_1_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Ad_1_users')
   Additional_User_2_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Ad_1_users')
   Additional_User_3_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Status_of_the_project = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE_1)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Finish_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Supporting_Documents = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)


   def __str__(self):
       return self.Project_Name

   class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "List Of Projects"

class Bug(models.Model):

   STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Unassigned', 'Unassigned'),
       ('Assigned', 'Assigned'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
       ('Tested', 'tested'),
       ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
   )
   STATUS_CHOICE_1 = (
       ('Bug', 'Bug'),
       ('Issue', 'Issue'),
       ('Enhancement', 'Enhancement'),
       ('Not an issue or bug', 'Not an issue or bug'),
       ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
   )
   Project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Issue_Title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Situation_Type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICE_1)
   Basic_Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Detailed_Description = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Status = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
   Assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Assigned_to_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Admin_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reported_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reporters_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reported_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Deadline_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Supporting_Documents_By_Reporter = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Project_Managers_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Project_Manager = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Technicians_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Technician = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Testers_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Tester = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.Project + ' (' + self.Situation_Type + ') ' + ' [' + self.Status + '] '


   def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
       if self.id:
           user=self.Assigned_to
           self.Assigned_to_Mail_ID=user.email
       send_mail(self.Admin_Mail_ID, ass=self.Assigned_to_Mail_ID)
       super(Bug, self).save()

   class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "Projects Tasks/Issues"




def send_mail(admin,ass):
    email=EmailMessage('Changes made to Task','Changes have been made to one of your Task reports and we hereby request you to have a look at it at the earliest.', to=[admin,ass])
    email.send()
```

This is a project that I've been working on for quite some time. I dont have a lot of experience in Django/Python..

**1) Database Key related isssue**

*How do I extract the email ID of the users and make it get autofilled when the user of the admin site chooses the Users Name using the drop down list?*

**2) Alternate Database Design Ideas**

*What is the best way to optimize the Users list? Is there any other way you guys could suggest me (a noob) to make the website in such a way that the Additional users could be added without limiting the website to accommodate only 3 Additional users?*

**3) `related_name` Issue**

*Why am I getting the following error when I use `related_name=`? How do I fix it?*

```
ERRORS:
Issues.Project.Additional_User_1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_2'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_1' or 'Project.Additional_User_2'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_3'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_1' or 'Project.Additional_User_3'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_1: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_1' clashes with reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_2'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_1' or 'Project.Additional_User_2'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_1: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_1' clashes with reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_3'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_1' or 'Project.Additional_User_3'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_2: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_2' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_1'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_2' or 'Project.Additional_User_1'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_2: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_2' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_3'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_2' or 'Project.Additional_User_3'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_2: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_2' clashes with reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_1'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_2' or 'Project.Additional_User_1'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_2: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_2' clashes with reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_3'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_2' or 'Project.Additional_User_3'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_3: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_3' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_1'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_3' or 'Project.Additional_User_1'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_3: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_3' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Project.Additional_User_2'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_3' or 'Project.Additional_User_2'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_3: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_3' clashes with reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_1'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_3' or 'Project.Additional_User_1'.
Issues.Project.Additional_User_3: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_3' clashes with reverse query name for 'Project.Additional_User_2'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.Additional_User_3' or 'Project.Additional_User_2'.
```

Please do keep in mind that I'm still a beginner and dont have a lot of knowledge about the subject. You might have to be a bit more descriptive for me to understand what you mean.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Kaushal - could you split this into three separate questions please :)

Comment: I'm sorry @MichealJRoberts for doing this, But the last time I did that, I was asked to make a single post with all the questions in it. Which is why I did this..

Comment: I think these questions are unrelated enough to warrant individual questions: for example, for us to be able to help you with question/issue 3 we need more than just your error trace. Question 4 is certainly a great question (not 100% sure both a and b are possible) but, nonetheless, warrants it's own question.

Comment: @MichealJRoberts I shall definitely keep what you said in mind the next time I post a question. But for now, Could you help me with any of these issues? I'm really curious to find out how to implement this website..

Comment: Split out the question and I might be able to help with some of the issues you've encountered.

Comment: I can't answer your question until they are split out into separate questions - if I add an answer future people who come to this question won't be able to know what exactly I've answered. Please split this out into 5 separate questions.

Comment: Hi Kaushal - the issue is when I post an answer to say part 3, people will thinking it is being dealt with and answered. Please split up into 4/5 separate SO questions. It's not possible to answer hosting, model optimisation and bug related questions all at the same time. It's too messy.

Comment: @MichealJRoberts I've reduced it to 3 related questions.
I can post only once every 1 and a half hours.. I guess, Ill post the other 2 questions later then..

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question 3 is as follows:

Admin_Name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Admin_Name_users+')

Using the table's name first followed by a `.` and then at the end, add a `+`